# Multiple discriminators for same type

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, npgsql

I got the following types

```
internal enum IssueType
{
    First,
    Second,
    Special
}

internal class Issue
{
    public int       Id    { get; set; }
    public string    Title { get; set; }
    public IssueType Type  { get; set; }
}

internal class SpecialIssue : Issue
{
    public string Payload { get; set; }
}
```

Some issue types map to certain subclasses, like `Special` would map to `SpecialIssue` in this case. Others just map to `Issue` i.e. there are several `IssueType`s without special subclasses.

Now I would like to have an `Issues` table to hold all these issues so I configured `Issue.Type` as a discriminator value.

```
builder.HasDiscriminator(x => x.Type)
       .HasValue<Issue>(IssueType.First)
       .HasValue<Issue>(IssueType.Second)
       .HasValue<SpecialIssue>(IssueType.Special);
```

Unfortunately it seems that I cannot set multiple discriminator values for the same type so at runtime I get errors stating that some discriminators weren't mapped although I did.

What I would like to achieve is to map all subclasses to their respective discriminators and have some kind of "fallback" that maps to `Issue` (or just map any remaining `IssueType` to the `Issue` type manually).

Is it possible to achieve this? I couldn't figure out any way to get EFCore to do this.
I'm currently using EFCore 5.0.10.

Comment: Discriminator by definition uniquely identifies the type (think of it as type ID). That's why you can't have multiple discriminator values for a single type. It has nothing to do with EF Core.

Comment: @IvanStoev thanks for your comment. Maybe I have to ask the EFCore team directly as I think this is kind of a bug or missing feature and should be possible. I see discriminators as a hint to EF how certain records have to get read from the database. So why not state that discriminator X,Y,Z have essentially the same representation? For this to work I now have to create several dummy types just for the sake of having different types but without any additional value :/

Comment: @TorbenJ discriminators aren't only for reading, they're also for writing. With the code above, say you ask EF Core to save an `Issue`, which discriminator should actually get written to the database, `First` or `Second`?

Comment: @ShayRojansky well in both cases the runtime type would be `Issue` thus both instances would have a `Type` property with values `First` or `Second`. So both instances would get written to the table with their respective `Type` value. Writing to the database isn't a problem. At least I could create several `Issue` instances with different `Type` values and write them to the database. The issue occurs only when reading from the database.

Comment: Which one though, `First` or `Second`? EF assigns each CLR type a single discriminator value, but you seem to want to associate two discriminator values with a single CLR type, so it's not clear what would get written.

Comment: Also, you cannot have a single "fallback" discriminator for all subtypes which haven't been explicitly configured, since when reading them back, EF wouldn't know which CLR type to materialize. Basically you need a one-to-one mapping between CLR types and discriminator values.

Comment: @ShayRojansky ok now that's interesting. it seems that ef really only writes only one type value I could have sworn that both of them were written in earlier tests but as `Second` is configured after `First` the `Second` value always gets written instead. Hmm okay that's unfortunate maybe I did something different which resulted in the expected result. Yeah there is a 1:1 mapping although I don't understand why they don't allow 1:n mappings instead :/ Maybe that's something I would have to implement by myself to work as expected. Thanks for your notes :)

Comment: Re 1:n mapping, remember EF has to both read and write your entity types unambiguously. This really does require a 1:1 mapping, as EF needs to know which discriminator value to write for a given CLR type (write), and which CLR type to materialize from a given database discriminator value (read).

Comment: Generally speaking, you shouldn't be using informational property as discriminator. Neither it should be mutable. The best is to make it shadow and never manipulate directly. This way EF will maintain the invariants between entityInstance.GetType() -> discriminator value (when writing) and discriminator value -> type to be created (when reading). Also better not reuse base entity since there is no easy way do distinguish between base and derived entity (the `is` operator returns true for both). Make the base entity abstract, and create concrete derived types for each discriminator value.